# Nodemcu and NRF24L01

Tags: nodemcu

I will start by asking can the nodemcu and nrf24l01 be setup as a receiver.Im trying to read basic pir sensor data sent from arduino nano and  a nrf24l01 set as transmitter. I want to receive this data on nodemcu and a nrf24l01 set as a receiver. The problem is nodemcu serial monitor and tft display is showing nothing. The nrf's rec/transmitter work perfectly when connected to arduino nanos. My loop code will not cyle on the esp8266 and nrf24l01, which is verified by no data on the tft display and serial monitor showing no received data. If I disconnect either sck, mosi or miso the loop code will cycle but no data is received.

My connections

```
Nodemcu       NRF24L01
D8 -----------> CE
D3 -----------> CSN
D5 -----------> SCK
D6 -----------> MISO
D7 -----------> MOSI
```

My connections

```
 Nano           NRF24L01
Pin  7 ---------> CE
Pin  8 ---------> CSN
Pin 13 ---------> SCK
Pin 12 ---------> MISO
Pin 11 ---------> MOSI
```

!!!!!!Nodemcu and NRF24 Code!!!!!

```
#include <SPI.h>  
#include "RF24.h" 

#define CE D8
#define CSN D3
RF24 myRadio (CE, CSN);

 byte addresses[][6] = {"0","1"}; 

struct package
{
  int id=0;
  float VALUE = 0.0;
  char  text[100] ="empty";
};
typedef struct package Package;
Package data;

int led = D0;

void setup() 
{
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(115200);

  myRadio.begin(); 
  myRadio.setChannel(115); 
  myRadio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MAX);
  myRadio.setDataRate( RF24_250KBPS ) ; 
  myRadio.openReadingPipe(1, addresses[0]);
  myRadio.startListening();
  delay(1000);
}


void loop()  
{

  if ( myRadio.available()) 
  {
    while (myRadio.available())
    {
    myRadio.read(&data, sizeof(data));
    Serial.print("\nPackage:");             //Serial Monitor Text
    Serial.print(data.id);                  //id of data packag
    Serial.print("\n");                     //newline
    Serial.println(data.VALUE);       //text to receiver line 2
    Serial.println(data.text);  //text to receiver line 3

    digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
    delay(500);
    digitalWrite(led, LOW);
    delay(500);
   }

   }
}

!!!!!!Nano and NRF24 Code!!!!!

#include "RF24.h"

RF24 myRadio (7, 8);
byte addresses[][6] = {"0", "1"};

struct package
{
  int id = 1;
  float VALUE ;    
  char  text[100] = "Sensor <1> Transfer";   //text to receiver 
};
typedef struct package Package;
Package data;


const int pinSensor = 4; // output signal pin of laser module/laser pointer
int PirSensor = 3; 

int led = 2;
void setup()
{
  pinMode(pinSensor, INPUT); // set the laser pin to output mode
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);
  Serial.begin(115200);

  myRadio.begin();
  myRadio.setChannel(115);
  myRadio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MAX);
  myRadio.setDataRate( RF24_250KBPS ) ;
  myRadio.setCRCLength(RF24_CRC_16); // Set CRC length to 16-bit to ensure quality of data
  myRadio.openWritingPipe( addresses[0]);
  myRadio.stopListening();
  delay(1000);
  }

void loop()
{
 PirSensor = digitalRead(pinSensor); // receiver/detector send either LOW or HIGH 
  if (PirSensor == 1){
    data1.VALUE = 1.00;
    Serial.print("Motion ");
    Serial.println(data.VALUE); // send value to console

    myRadio.write(&data, sizeof(data));

  Serial.print("\nPackage:");
  Serial.print(data.id);
  Serial.print("\n");
  Serial.println(data.VALUE);
  Serial.println(data.text);

  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);
  delay(500);
  } 
else{
    data.VALUE = 0.00;
    Serial.print("No Motion");
    Serial.println(data.VALUE); // send value to console

    myRadio.write(&data, sizeof(data));

  Serial.print("\nPackage:");
  Serial.print(data.id);
  Serial.print("\n");
  Serial.println(data.VALUE);
  Serial.println(data.text);

  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);
  delay(500);
}
}
```

Comment: You should probably start by validating the SPI and control connections.  Perhaps you can write a simple sketch to read an nRF24 register and print that via serial.  Do you have a scope or logic analyzer you can probe with?   At the least double check that your ESP8266 pin assignments are correct for an SPI peripheral.

Comment: you might want to look into ESPNOW, it kinda obsoletes the nrf chip...